# Is it possible to add characters to word separators without triggering the completions in Sublimetext3?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have this word separators: `"word_separators": "./\\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?"` 
and i want that the '/' character will be a separator between words (e.g module/template), but that character should not trigger the auto-complete.
Is it possible?

Comment: couldn't reproduce the behavior. Please add more details